# How to put text in infinity symbol on GIMP or Inkscape!

Tags: inkscape, gimp, path

I'm trying to do something in this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt-fI-GKs24 but with GIMP or Inkscape.
So, basically, if I convert the infinity symbol to a path, is there an option to put text IN a path, instead of along a path? Just something that looks like the video shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no text inside a path function in Inkscape or GIMP. There are ways to flow text in a rectangle or shape in Inkscape, but it won't work for what you want.

You can put [text on a path in Inkscape](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/putting-text-on-path.html?).  I wouldn't use GIMP for this. GIMP is a photo editor. Better to do this in vector software.

I wouldn't convert the infinity symbol to a path either - it's unlikely to work. Instead I'd draw a path over the symbol to place the text on, using the Bézier Tool (aka Pen Tool).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to maybe not do this with the pen tool because I'm pretty confused on how it works, but I'll try it and see how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, learning to use the Pen Tool is pretty crucial for Inkscape, and it's a skill that takes a while to master. Some might say it's actually "the" most important tool in the toolbox.

Comment: Yea, I totally agree! I'm more of a raster person, and really don't use Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator. The most I do is edit some existing SVGs. I'll probably try to learn it and see how it goes.

Comment: There's a good tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVjJfx2oc5w&ab_channel=LogosByNick

Comment: Thank you! I'll go watch it later and just first try to make some simpler shapes.

Comment: Watch [this screen recording](https://imgur.com/vMKPClk) I made showing how I made the path.